# how can i make my webpack dev server boot faster inside docker in windows 11

Tags: windows, docker, webpack, docker-compose

I work as a frontend dev in a system composed of multiple backend services built with nodejs and java and a SPA frontend developed with vue 2.

The local dev environment is enabled using docker and docker-compose with services for each sw component.

The web app is bundled using webpack and the webpack-dev-server is used to serve it in the local environment with the much-needed hot module replacement feature.

When starting the system through docker-compose in windows 11 most services begin in a reasonable time except for the web app which takes more than 10 minutes. My Linux colleagues do not suffer such pain (I accept your judging eyes for my Windows setup but I will probably never change that).

The docker-compose section for the web app is this

```yaml
  web-app:
    depends_on:
      - postgresdb
      - autenticador-api
    build:
      context: ./web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./web:/app
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
```

The Dockerfile mentioned in the docker-compose yml is like this:

```
FROM node:14
RUN npm -v
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

There is also a dockerigone

```
npm-debug.log
node_modules
package-lock.json
```

My docker desktop version is 4.19.0
The webpack related dependencies are "webpack": "^5.37.0", "webpack-bundle-analyzer": ^4.4.2", "webpack-cli": "4.2.0" and "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.0".
My OS is windows 11 v22H2

The hardware is a reasonable i7-12700H with 16 GB of ram and an SSD drive.

Can anyone suggest some measures I could take to improve the web dev server starting time without changing the OS, docker, and webpack?